# vuejs - router going to homepage on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following problem with my vuejs app.
Every refresh on a page other than the home page results in a redirect to the home page.

Here is my `router.js`

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/project/:slug",
    name: "Project",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Project.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/projecttimeline/",
    name: "ProjectTimeline",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/ProjectTimeline.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/privacypolicy/",
    name: "PrivacyPolicy",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/PrivacyPolicy.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    document.getElementById("app").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "instant" });
  }
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.query.lang) {
    var setLocale = from.query.lang || "ro";
    to.query.lang = setLocale;
    next({ path: to.path, query: to.query });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Is this something related to the vue history?

Comment: so you're using vue-router in hash mode?

Comment: i think this is vue-router behavior

Comment: true, hash is default.

Comment: @Bravo could this be something related to the server settings?

Comment: if you want to use history mode, you do need to set up the server correctly - as documented in vue-router *documentation* - however, you don't seem to be using history mode, so, it's a moot point